# Standard Euclidean topology over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

> [image: Here is The question]

Given the set
$$
A=\left\{\frac 1 n + 1 \ \Bigg|\ n\in  \mathbb{N}\right\},
$$

I know this is not an open set.

But is this $A$ bounded, compact or closed?

Comment: How do you know it's not open? Boundedness is really easy; as for closedness, can you think to a limit point of $A$?

Comment: The edit may have changed the question. It's not clear that "$1/(n+1)$" was meant. (But rather $1+1/n$).

Comment: @DanielRust if a set is closed and bounded then it is Compact.If it is finite set then its bounded.In the above case if i take 1 then the line goes to infinity so which would be infinity,so its open.

Answer (score 3):

- $A$ is **not closed**, because $1$ is a limit point of $A$ and $1\not\in A$.
- It is **not compact** because it is not closed.
- It is **bounded** because $1\le \frac{1}{n}+1\le 2$.

Answer (score 0):

here $1$ is the only *limit point* and $A\in (1,2] $ . So the *set is bounded and is semi-open or semi-closed* and since it is *not closed* , therefore *it is not compact*.